# Polymorphism in template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have the following structure:

**Two possible algorithms**, one inherits the other, whose template parameter is a self defined container class.

```
template <class C>
class AlgBase {
    protected:
        C c;
};

template <class C>
class AlgDerived : public AlgBase<C> {};
```

The container class is templated as well, and the parameters are also related by inheritance:

```
class TParamBase {};
class TParamDerived : public TParamBase {};

template <class T> // T is TParamBase or TParamDerived
class Container {
    protected:
        T t_;
};
```

Now, in my main, I want to do the following:

```
typedef Container<TParamBase> ContainerBase;
typedef Container<TParamDerived> ContainerDerived;

int main (int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    vector<AlgBase<ContainerBase>* > algs;
    algs.push_back(new AlgBase<ContainerBase>);
    algs.push_back(new AlgDerived<ContainerBase>);
    algs.push_back(new AlgDerived<ContainerDerived>);
}
```

The first two `push_back` work since they use `ContainerBase`. The third fails because the use of `ContainerDerived`. The error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >*>::push_back(AlgDerived<Container<TParamDerived> >*)’
     algs.push_back(new AlgDerived<ContainerDerived>);
                                                    ^
main.cpp:34:52: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/vector:64:0,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >*; _Alloc = std::allocator<AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >*]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘AlgDerived<Container<TParamDerived> >*’ to ‘AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >* const&’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >*; _Alloc = std::allocator<AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >*]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘AlgDerived<Container<TParamDerived> >*’ to ‘AlgBase<Container<TParamBase> >*&&’
```

The only solution I have in mind is to forget about `TParamBase` and `TParamDerived` and only use one class, but this is a bit inefficient since I will be creating and allocating elements not used.

Is there any other solution to make the third `push_back` work?

Thank you!

Comment: @gha.st thank you, I saw that one but for some reason I thought it was not the same. I will check it ouy.

Comment: If you find any difficulties applying a workaround, please let us know. If you find that the duplicate doesn't help you solve the problem, we can discuss to reopen your question.

Comment: Your `ContainerBase` and `ContainerDerived` are fundamentally unrelated.  Consider replacing both with a `Container<TParamBase*>` (or smart pointer equivalent).